# What causes the spirals to be inward in the bubble chamber images?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, experimental-physics, electrons, particle-detectors

[image]

My understanding is that the circular paths are caused by the action of the Lorentz force on the electrons and positrons.

However, I'm not sure why the circular paths are going *inward.* I have two ideas in mind. The first is that this could be caused by drag forces from the atmosphere of the bubble chamber. The second possibility is that this is caused by Bremsstrahlung radiation.

Which of the two factors plays a more significant role? Is there any calculation/evidence/reference to support one answer over the other?

**Edit:** Changed "cloud chamber" to "bubble chamber."

Comment: Friction in a classical sense is a non-issue. It's not even well defined. But there are multiple processes that *do* cuase the steady loss of energy. You want the chapter "Passage of particles through matter" from [the particle data Book](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/contents_sports.html).

Comment: I think this must be a bubble chambber picture, I do not think they had such good magnetic fields in cloud chamers, in fact it says so in the legend " A bubble chamber works on the same principle as a cloud chamber except that spiral tracks are seen as well." https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-make-a-cloud-chamber-4153805

Comment: To get more insides into the process I asked a next question about [In an undulator charges radiate and get deflected. What is the primary and what is the secondary process?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/514153/in-an-undulator-charges-radiate-and-get-deflected-what-is-the-primary-and-what)

Answer (score 7):

In a cloud chamber (or any other detector) the particles are *moving through a material medium*, so they steadily lose energy (that can also suddenly lose energy which results in a kink in the track).

Less energy means lower speed which means less momentum $p$, and the radius of curvature $R$ goes by
$$ R = \frac{p}{qB} \;, $$
where $q$ is the particles charge and $B$ the strength of the magnetic field.

So, as energy is lost, the curve gets tighter and tighter.

Comment: I‘m not convinced. OP asks explicitly for calculation/evidence/reference. In your answer you don’t give any evidence that your statement “steadily loses energy” indeed is caused by the medium and not, as proposed, by bremsstrahlung.

Answer (score 3):

Low energy electrons lose energy to ionization of the medium they’re traversing. The ionization comes from the charged particle interacting electrically with atomic electrons as it moves through atoms.

This is a good thing: that ionization is what the chamber is detecting and displaying.

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen in the label of the picture you show, it is a [bubble chamber](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-make-a-cloud-chamber-4153805) picture. The label says :

" A bubble chamber works on the same principle as a cloud chamber except that spiral tracks are seen as well."

[Cloud and bubble chambers](https://www.s-cool.co.uk/a-level/physics/radioactivity/revise-it/cloud-and-bubble-chambers) make charge particle tracks visible by their scattering off atoms of the medium, ionizing them and creating the little accumulation of "bubbles"  which  reflects the light so a photograph is taken. The little dots are visible and can be photographed. Cloud chambers are not used in magnetic fields so spirals are not seen.

This scattering generates energy loss as a particle traverses the medium and this loss is seen in the reduction of the radius as shown in the answer by dmckee .

There is also the radiation loss of a charged particle turning in a circle , called [synchrotron radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/synchrotron.html#:~:targetText=Synchrotron%20radiation%20is%20the%20name,path%20will%20emit%20electromagnetic%20radiation.), which for the picture shown is in the Xray region, i.e. not enough energy to give the drastic reduction in radius seen in the picture. The effect of radiation loss to the ionization curve is shown in the link, in page 4.

There are ionization curves of [particles through](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf) matter, and are used in analysing bubble chamber pictures, because they depend on the momentum and mass of the particle, and allow to identify the low momentum  tracks in the bubble chamber experiments, but that is another story.

Comment: Anna, what causes the deflection?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler  In all bubble chambers there is a strong magnetic field imposed of order of Tesla, perpendicular to the picture shown above .This allows to measure the momenta by   $BQv=mv^2/R$ setting the certifugal equal to the cenripetal to first order ( without ionisation corrections)

Comment: Anna, if the collisions would be the main cause of the deflection, it should be a chaotic deflection in different directions and not a spiral path? Not having the magnetic field the spiral path would not occur, right?

Comment: “ The entire chamber is subject to a constant magnetic field, which causes charged particles to travel in helical paths whose radius is determined by their charge-to-mass ratios and their velocities.”

Comment: @HolgerFiedler  ionisations are very tiny collisions, of order ev, hydrogen is ionized.so it is like friction, but the magnetic field is always in the same direction, so the circle radius becomes a teeny tiny bit smaller for each ionization loss.

Comment: That is what I told in my answer. Or not?

Comment: @Holger No, at is *not* what you've stated in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us compare this phenomenon with this in a particle accelerator, a [undulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undulator) or a [free-electron laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser).

The difference to a cloud chamber is the high vacuum inside these devices. All other “ingredients” are the same: charged particles, moving straight forwards and an external magnetic field.

Even without the collision with other particles the charges radiate, and in the same time get deflected (change their direction) and loose kinetic energy. So the answers which claim that the collisions are the only reason for the spiral path, have been given somewhat hastily.

Comment: "the answers which claim that the collisions are the only reason for the spiral path" have been posted by people who know what they are talking about. Have you got suitable references to credible literature to support your claim that radiative losses are non-negligible in cloud-chamber tracks? Or is this yet another answer with misinformation posted because you couldn't be bothered to do your research before posting?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty “The entire chamber is subject to a constant magnetic field, which causes charged particles to travel in helical paths whose radius is determined by their charge-to-mass ratios and their velocities.“

Comment: That is just the normal, conservative motion of a charged particle in a magnetic field and it will result in helical or circular trajectories, not spirals, as is the issue here. (In particular, note that spirals and helices are different things.) Please refrain from posting misinformation when you do not know what you're talking about - it is an abuse of the site to require others to clean up your messes after you.

Comment: If you don't understand the distinctions here, please read a suitable textbook - I would recommend Halliday and Resnick's *Fundamentals of Physics* or Sears and Zemansky's *University Physics*, particularly if introductory EM textbooks (say, Griffiths) seem too daunting.