# In an undulator charges radiate and get deflected. What is the primary and what is the secondary process?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

Moving charged particles under the influence of an external field like in undulators or in free-electron lasers get deflected and radiate. Or radiate and get deflected. What causes what?

The background is that the Lorentz force tells us only, that moving charged particles get deflected in an external magnetic field. This law was derived from a current carrying wire in a magnetic field, where the radiation was not monitored. On the other side it is known that accelerated charges radiate. Both phenomena - deflection and radiation - always take place at the same time. What causes what?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider your situation for two different particles with the same charge and velocity and different masses. Let us choose the magnetic fields of the undulator in such a way that these particles have the same acceleration, i.e., the magnetic field and the Lorentz force will be greater for the heavier particle. The resulting radiation will be the same for both particles as the charges and the trajectories are the same. If it were radiation that causes the deflection, it would exert the same force on the particles, so the acceleration would be different for the two particles. So this seems to suggest that it is deflection that causes radiation in your situation, not the other way round. Of course, in some other situation external radiation can cause  deflection.

Comment: That's a nice approach. Could you provide data that the electron and the proton (besides the fact that they are deflected in opposite directions) emit the same radiation under the circumstances you describe?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler : radiation of a charge moving along a certain trajectory depends on its charge, but not on its mass (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liénard-Wiechert_potential). Instead of an electron and a proton we can consider a positron and a proton to have the same trajectory.